# Exchange 2007 SP2 install issue

Tags: exchange-2007, imap, pop3, outlook-web-app

We currentlty have a Windows Server 2003 x64 running Exchange 2007 SP2. We just recently updated to SP2. I believe the person that was running the update might have tried to install it twice.

Our issue is that now the imap4, pop3 and Microsoft Exchange Unified Messaging services are not starting.

Unfortunately Exchange 2007 is not my strongest suit, if you could point me in a direction of even being able to start to troubleshoot this, it would be appreciated. Google doesn't seem to show much for the specific environment I have.

OWA is also giving an error page:

> ### Server Error in '/owa' Application.
>
> Runtime Error  Description: An
>   application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this
>   specific error message to be viewable
>   on remote machines, please create a
>    tag within a
>   "web.config" configuration file
>   located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This
>    tag should then have
>   its "mode" attribute set to "Off".
>
> Notes: The current error page you are
>   seeing can be replaced by a custom
>   error page by modifying the
>   "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's 
>   configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

The event's in the application log are

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   .NET Runtime 2.0 Error Reporting
Event ID:   1000
Description:
Faulting application microsoft.exchange.pop3service.exe, version 8.2.176.2, stamp 4a8b5a40, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.2.3790.4480, stamp 49c51cdd, debug? 0, fault address 0x000000000000dd50.

Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 5/6/2011 8:13:00 AM 
Event time (UTC): 5/6/2011 3:13:00 PM 
Event ID: 2bbdaec2ea304f67b79e9d522462df7d 
Event sequence: 3638 
Event occurrence: 3635 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Autodiscover-1-129491252467161130 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Autodiscover 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\Autodiscover\ 
    Machine name: 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 2360 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://fqdn:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml 
    Request path: /Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml 
    User host address: x.x.x.x 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 8 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Exchange.Autodiscover.Global.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   MSExchange Unified Messaging
Event Category: UMService 
Event ID:   1038
Description:
The Microsoft Exchange Unified Messaging service was unable to start. More information: "The service was unable to start listening for SIP calls. The connection manager was unable to listen using the address and port supplied."

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   MSExchange Unified Messaging
Event Category: UMService 
Event ID:   1104
Description:
The Unified Messaging Service was unable to read the UM worker process retire time from the configuration data. The UM worker process retire time is being set to the default value, which is "1800". Reason: "Did not find the DialPlan object for server in the Active Directory. "



Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Event Category: Web Event 
Event ID:   1309
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 5/6/2011 8:12:46 AM 
Event time (UTC): 5/6/2011 3:12:46 PM 
Event ID: 33c44d2c648f46af9b4dcb75eddc25cb 
Event sequence: 554 
Event occurrence: 551 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/EWS-1-129491252375894370 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /EWS 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\ClientAccess\exchweb\EWS\ 
    Machine name:  

Process information: 
    Process ID: 7900 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: FileNotFoundException 
    Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: https://fqdn:443/EWS/Exchange.asmx 
    Request path: /EWS/Exchange.asmx 
    User host address: x.x.x.x 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 9 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at Microsoft.Exchange.Services.AuthorizationModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a few errors that the system cannot find "Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics" assembly.  This might indicate that the install was corrupted.  You might want to try uninstalling and reinstalling the client access role and see if that corrects the issue.

Also, your unified messaging error seems kind of ominous -- it's reporting that it cannot find the dialplan objects in your active directory.  If you already had a running UM infrastructure, it's possible the dialplan objects were corrupted somehow in AD.

I would seriously consider calling Microsoft support for help at this point, if this is a mission critical system.

Comment: Mircosoft tried to patch it up, but in the end, they said to just go with SP3. I guess that was the obvious answer. Thanks!